# How to set label after input field in React.js Formik (Input)?

Tags: css, reactjs, input, label, formik

I would need to set the text of the Label, for the Formik Input Component, after the input field.
I am not sure how to target it and how to apply CSS.

So a code sample:

```
<div className="editable-job-title">
      {isEditing ? (
        <Formik
          validateOnMount={true}
          enableReinitialize
          initialValues={user}
          validationSchema={userNameValidationSchema}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {(props) => (
            <Form>
                <Input
                name="job_title"
                type="text"
                label={t('userForm.job_title.label')}
              />
              <FormActions className="user-form-page__form-action">
                <RoundButton
                  type="button"
                  onClick={stopEditing}
                  className="button button--cancel">
                  <Icon icon={x} />
                </RoundButton>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
```

[image]

So basically, I would need the Job Title text to be below the field.
Or any other nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use `<Field>` element from `formik`.

[image]

If this is the case, check it out on https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-tests-onchange-mo4fi?file=/src/App.js

```
import { Field, Formik, Form } from "formik";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

<Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={() => alert("submitted!")}
    >
      <Form>
        <Field name="email">
          {(props) => (
            <>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                placeholder={props.field.name}
                label={props.field.name}
                {...props.field}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </Field>
        ...
```